# Crystal Reports 11 - find Min/Max Values > and < 2000000

Tags: crystal-reports, max, min

Greetings All;

```
    Payment Numbers
    30845
    30846
    200000258
    200000257
    200000256
    200000255
    200000254
    200000253
    30847
    30848
    30849
    30850
```

Need CR formula to get the max and Min payment number for numbers > 200 Million (200000000):
        Max  > 200 Million = 200000258
        Min  > 200 Million = 200000253

Need CR formula to get the max and Min payment number for numbers < 200 Million (200000000):
        Max  < 200 Million = 30850
        Min  < 200 Million = 30845

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance your your assistance.

Comment: Appears to work (MAX >20000000) :

        if Maximum({CHK_mdb.Payment number})>20000000 then {CHK_mdb.Payment number} = 200000258

Does not to work (MIN <20000000) :

        if Minimum({CHK_mdb.Payment number})>20000000 then {CHK_mdb.Payment number} = 0

Comment: Sorry for the typo.    Does not to work (MIN > 20000000) :

        if Minimum({CHK_mdb.Payment number})>20000000 then {CHK_mdb.Payment number} = 0

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 formulas one for `>20000000` and other for `<200000000`.

@formula1

```
Shared StringVar Array x;
if databasefield > 200000000
then 
    x:=x+totext(Databasefiled.column));      // this is the column that holds the values you used in question
1
```

@formula2

```
Shared StringVar Array y;
if databasefield < 200000000
then 
y:=y+totext(Databasefiled.column));      // this is the column that holds the values you used in question
1
```

now place these formulas to the rightmost part of the section you required and supress.

now create 4 more formulas for display.

@display1_max

```
EvaluateAfter(@formula1)  // maximum for >200000000
Shared StringVar Array x;
Maximum(x);
```

@display1_min

```
EvaluateAfter(@formula1)  // minimum for >200000000
Shared StringVar Array x;
Minimum(x);
```

@display2_max

```
EvaluateAfter(@formula2)  // maximum for <200000000
Shared StringVar Array y;
Maximum(y);
```

@display2_min

```
EvaluateAfter(@formula1)  // minimum for <200000000
Shared StringVar Array y;
Minimum(y);
```

Comment: Thanks Siva for the prompt response.

Having a problem with the first of the last 4 formulas.

As written, the following display1_max formula generates this error:
  "the ) is Missing"

        @display1_max

        EvaluateAfter(@formula1)  // maximum for >200000000
        Shared StringVar x;
        Maximum(x);


display1_max formula Modified to this generates this error:
   Maximum(x) <----"A field is required here"


        EvaluateAfter({@@formula1});  // maximum for >200000000
        Shared StringVar x;
        Maximum(x);


Your thoughts?

Comment: first thing dont write this line `// maximum for >200000000 ` in formula this just for explanation.. and for rest of errros changed my solution. check from first to last added `Array` for varaible. Let me know if you still face issue